# Observing AVAudioSession not firing notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudiosession

In the app I am currently building, I need to process a few things depending on `[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]`'s current category. This category will change during runtime, and I am trying to keep track of the changes by observing `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification` in NotificationCenter.

However, no matter what I try the notification is not being fired (or at least nothing is being received by my selector method).

***Some test sample code;***

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sessionRouteDidChange:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];
   return YES;
}
- (void)sessionRouteDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"SESSION ROUTE CHANGED");
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)changeAudioCategory:(AVAudioSessionCategory)category{
       [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
        BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:category error:&setCategoryError];
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR");
        }
        [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

        /* Logging the current category */
        NSLog(@"AVAUDIOSESSION CATEGORY %@", audioSession.category);
}
```

I am expecting the observer I have set up in `AppDelegate` to send a notification to `sessionRouteDidChange` upon changing category inside this method, but nothing happens.

***What I have tried;***

- Testing on multiple iOS versions and iPhone models, but none worked
- Double and triple checked that I am not removing the observer anywhere

Any ideas about what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the category is not a route change, so it doesn't post a notification. What you want is to [KVO observe](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-BAJEAIEE) the `category` property.

Route changes occur when you change the audio route, for example, when you plug-in earphones.

Comment: I see! AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange had me completely convinced I could get notified on category change. I'm not sure the category property is KVO compliant though.. I guess I'll have to find some other way to solve this :) Thank you so much!